# パスワードのハッシュ化がされない。

Tags: php, mysql

#### 環境

mamp
php 7.4
mysql 5.7
phpmyadmin

*****やりたいこととできないこと*****
現在の機能としてはsignup.phpで新規登録してname,passwordカラムをusersテーブルに保存した後、check.phpにリダイレクトして、check.phpはsignup.phpで投稿した値ををセッションで保持しており、表示できるというものです。
この機能にパスワードのハッシュ化をしようとするとテーブルに値が保存されない問題が起きてしまいます。
ハッシュ化する前は、もちろん正常に新規登録した後、usersテーブルに値が保存されていました。

*****実施した手順とその結果*****
sha1メソッドと、password_hashを使う。

**signup.php**

```php
<?php

session_start();
require('../dbconnect.php');

if ($_POST['name'] === '') {
 $error['name'] = 'blank';
}

if ($_POST['password'] === '') {
 $error['password'] = 'blank';
}

if (!empty($_POST['name'] && $_POST['password'])) {
 $_SESSION['join'] = $_POST;
 $name = $_POST['name'];
// ここから〜⭐️
 //$password = $_POST['password']; 
 $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 // $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
//ここまで

 $sql = 'INSERT into users(name, password) values(?, ?)';
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(array($name, $password));
 //$stmt = null;
 //$db = null;

 header('Location: check.php');
 exit();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>新規登録画面</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form action="" method="POST">
  名前
  <input type="text" name="name" id="" value="<?php print(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES)); ?>">
  <?php if ($error['name'] === 'blank') : ?>
   <p style="color: red;">名前を入力してください</p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div>
   パスワード
   <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php print(htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES)); ?>">
   <?php if ($error['password'] === 'blank') : ?>
    <p style="color: red;">パスワードを入力してください</p>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <input type="submit" name="signup" value="新規登録">
  </div>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**check.php**

```php
<?php
session_start();
require('../dbconnect.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['join'])) {
 header('Location: ./signup.php');
 exit();
}
?>
<p><?php print(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['join']['name'], ENT_QUOTES)); ?></p>
<p>パスワードは公開していません</p>
<a href="./signup.php">戻る</a>
```

結果は
password_hash、sha1どちらをつかっても値がusersテーブルに入りませんでした。ただセッションの保持は成功しておりcheck.phpのリダイレクトも保持した値の表示もできます。

試したことその２
var_dumpでmysqlのエラーメッセージを取得しようとした。

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'] && $_POST['password'])) {
 $_SESSION['join'] = $_POST;
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 //$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 //$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
 $sql = 'INSERT into users(name, password) values(?, ?)';
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $mysql_data = $stmt->execute(array($name, $password));
 var_dump($mysql_data);
 exit();

 header('Location: check.php');
 exit();
}
```

この場合、sha1メソッド、password_hashがfalse、使用していない場合はtrueを出力しました。

試したことその３
errorCodeメソッドを使用する。
[https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.errorcode.php　こちらを参考にしました。](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.errorcode.php%E3%80%80%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89%E3%82%92%E5%8F%82%E8%80%83%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82)

```php
<?php
try {
 $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=kadai3_1;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo "接続エラー: " . $e->getMessage();
}

if (!empty($_POST['name'] && $_POST['password'])) {
 $_SESSION['join'] = $_POST;
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 //$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 //$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
 $sql = 'INSERT into users(name, password) values(?, ?)';
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $mysql_data = $stmt->execute(array($name, $password));
 echo $db->errorCode();
 exit();

 header('Location: check.php');
 exit();
}
```

sha1,password_hash,ハッシュ化しない、これらどのケースも0が5つ表示されるという結果になりました。この結果に関してはなぜそうなったか正直全く検討がついていません。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考にした記事のURLは以下です。
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.password-hash.php
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.sha1.php

ハッシュしようとしたができない方のブランチのurl
https://github.com/masal9pse/internTasks/tree/hash_password/task3/kadai1/views
ハッシュ化していない正常に値が投入できるブランチ
https://github.com/masal9pse/internTasks/tree/master/task3/kadai1/views

何かアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いします。

Comment: DBにinsert時にエラーは出ていませんか？mysqlのエラーはきちんとハンドリングしてみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: 「ハッシュ化できない」と「テーブルに保存されない」は別の話なので、どの部分に問題があるのかを明確にする必要があると思います。

Comment: @keitaro_so 投稿時にcheck.phpにリダイレクトされますが、エラーは確認できませんでした。

Comment: @cubick どこの部分に問題があるのか申し訳ありませんが正直、検討がついていません。ただsha1、password_hashメソッドを使わずハッシュ化しない場合は正常にテーブルに保存されています。

Comment: どのようにmysqlのエラーをキャッチしていますか？ソースを見るとMySQLのエラーはキャッチしていなさそうですが。

Comment: https://github.com/masal9pse/internTasks/commit/428c071d1e8db768ee00707e1c955724649310ff　的外れかもしれませんが、このようにvar_dumpで取得してみたところ、sha1とpassword_hashを用いた場合はfalse、使用していない場合はtrueが出力されました。errorCodeという関数も使用して取得しようとしましたが、どのケースも0が5つ取得されました。

Comment: sha1の結果が、バイナリ形式だから保存できないかも

Answer (score 0):

usersテーブルの文字数制限を増やしてみたところ無事に問題が解決しました。案外単純なミスで拍子抜けしました。
質問に回答してくださった方、大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

```php
// create_users_table.php
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=kadai3_1;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "接続エラー: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// テーブル作成のSQLを作成
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
// もともと11文字だったところを100文字に変えたところsha1でもpassword_hashでもハッシュ化できました。
 password VARCHAR(100),
    registry_datetime DATETIME
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8';

// SQLを実行
$res = $db->query($sql);
echo '接続できました。';
```